# Subset a list based on specific strings

Tags: python, regex, string, text

I'm reading in a file and assigning it the variable "input_kws".

```
input_kws = open('words.txt','r')
```

Contents of "input_kws" are:

```
baseball
basketball
football
tennis
boxing
volleyball
```

I simply want to create a new list containing only words containing "ball".

Comment: What have you done so far? Please show your approach and where exactly you are stuck.

Answer (score 4):

Just check if 'ball' is in each string.

```
input_kws= 'baseball basketball football tennis'.split()

ball_sports = [word for word in input_kws if 'ball' in word]
>>>['baseball', 'basketball', 'football']
```

Alternatively, you could use `filter` to achieve the same results

```
f = filter(lambda x: 'ball' in x, input_kws) #Returns a generator
ball_sports = list(f)
```

And if generators aren't your thing, you can always do it with a loop

```
ball_sports = []
for sport in input_kws:
    if 'ball' in sport:
        ball_sports.append(sport)
```

This would fail if there were other sports in your list which had the substring 'ball'.  Example

```
input_kws= 'baseball basketball football tennis balloon'.split()
f = filter(lambda x: 'ball' in x, input_kws) #Returns a generator
ball_sports = list(f)
>>>['baseball', 'basketball', 'football','balloon']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can also use regex for finding ball in the string

```
import re

for line in open(r"words.txt","r"):
    if re.findall(r"ball",line) ==["ball"]:
        print(line)

baseball

basketball

football

volleyball
```

Comment: this works perfectly. thank you all.